# Problem booting to Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: boot, system

I clean installed Windows 7, and installed Ubuntu 14.04 afterwards. Rebooted, then booted straight to Ubuntu. Used Bootable Windows 7 USB and fixed the MBR in command prompt. Then rebooted and it booted straight to Windows, no Ubuntu option, used Live Ubuntu and installed and ran Boot-Repair this worked, but after reboot I finally got grub, but it only shows ubuntu.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10612519/

Hope someone can help me out, really would love to be able to learn how to use linux and maybe use it standalone in the future.

Comment: Why do you have GRUB installed in the MBRs of two different drives? Also, habe you tried running `update-grub`?

Comment: Good question, did try a different install before this one. Can I run update-grub from the terminal?

Comment: Update-grub worked, ty very much

Comment: @the_Seppi: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered quite a lot cases where Windows wouldn't boot any more after the alongside installation of Ubuntu. The thing I always try first is to renew the GRUB entries using the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I've experienced this to fix such boot problems most of the time. If it doesn't, I try it with Boot Repair.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)